# Need help with editing code in Python

Tags: python

I have only recently started to program in python. This is my first experience in programming.

This is the problem from [code academy](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/python-beginner-en-IZ9Ra/0/4?curriculum_id=4f89dab3d788890003000096#). I basically need to:

> "Write a function called `fizz_count` that takes a list x as input and returns the count of the string `"fizz"` in that list.
>
> For example, `fizz_count(["fizz","buzz","fizz"])` should return 2. "

Here is my code:

```
def fizz_count(x): 
    count = 0
    for a in x:
        if a == "fizz":
           return fizz_count(x) == 1 + count
        else:
           return fizz_count(x) == count
```

But this does not work. Where am I wrong?

Comment: welcome to programmers. This kind of question is off-topic. Please check http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please explain what you mean that your program doesn't work? What does it do when you run it? Please post any error messages and other output you get and also explain how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: I say it does work. What now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You appear to be using recursive programming but you are not understanding how that should work.

You are calling your function recursively, but recursive counting requires you to divide your problem into subproblems; solve one and delegate the rest to the recursive call, or split up the set into subproblems until you have a small set you know how to solve. You however are trying to solve the subproblem for all elements in the list instead, then passing the whole list to the recursive call. This just leads to an infinite recursion exception because you only ever look at the same problem set.

A recursive version would be:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    if not x:
        return 0
    return (1 if x[0] == 'fizz' else 0) + fizz_count(x[1:])
```

This just looks at the first element and delegates counting of the rest of the list to the recursive call. If the list is empty, 0 is returned.

Subdividing up the list into halves is another option, returning only when the list is empty or has just one element:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    lenx = len(x)
    if not lenx:
        return 0
    if lenx == 1:
        return (1 if x[0] == 'fizz' else 0)
    return fizz_count(x[:lenx//2]) + fizz_count(x[lenx//2:])
```

If you wanted to loop over the list and count that way (without recursion), increment `count` and only return when you completed the loop:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    count = 0
    for a in x:
        if a == 'fizz':
            count += 1
    return count
```

However, the simplest solution is to use the standard `list.count()` function:

```
def fizz_count(x):
    return x.count('fizz')
```

and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have only learnt about "loop over the list and count". Can you explain what count +=1 does? I don't get that line.

Comment: @upaudel: For immutable values such as integers, that is just a shorthand version of `count = count + 1`. The operator is called 'in-place add'; add up the value on the right to the name on the left.

Comment: Great! How or why did you decide not to use else statement?

Comment: There is no need to. The `else` case would be to add `0` to `count`, to which there is little point.